# Airflow custom operator variables

Tags: airflow, dockeroperator

I need to pass Airflow connection settings(AWS, Postgres) to docker container environment variables 
I'm trying to do this using custom Operator and BaseHook. \

```
class S3ToPostgresDockerOperator(DockerOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, aws_conn_id='aws_default', postgres_conn_id='postgres_default', **kwargs):
        super(S3ToPostgresDockerOperator, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.aws_conn = BaseHook.get_connection(aws_conn_id)
        self.pg_conn = BaseHook.get_connection(postgres_conn_id)
```

Is it possible to do something like that, or if not how should I do it?

```
    java_unpack_csv = S3ToPostgresDockerOperator(
        ...
        environment={
            'AWS_ACCESS_KEY': '{{ ??? }}',
            'AWS_SECRET_KEY': '{{ ??? }}'
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up the environment kwarg passed in the `DockerOperator` constructor.

For example,

```py
class S3ToPostgresDockerOperator(DockerOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, aws_conn_id='aws_default', postgres_conn_id='postgres_default', **kwargs):
        self.aws_conn = BaseHook.get_connection(aws_conn_id)
        self.pg_conn = BaseHook.get_connection(postgres_conn_id)
  
        credentials = self.aws_conn.get_credentials()
        kwargs['environment'] = dict(
            kwargs.pop('environment', {}),
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY=credentials.access_key,
            AWS_SECRET_KEY=credentials.secret_key,
            PG_DATABASE_URI=self.pg_conn.get_uri()
        )
        super(S3ToPostgresDockerOperator, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```